# Magento 2 Add Custom Tooltip to Shipping Methods On Checkout Page

Tags: magento2, shipping, shipping-methods, tooltip

I am using magento 2.3.3

I want to add tootlip in every shipping method

like:
Flat rate **(i) This is for flat rate information content**

I want to like this as above (in bold) after Flat rate

anyone help here

thanks in advance

[image]